# W/audio_hw_generic: pcm_read failed cannot read stream data: I/O error

Tags: java, android, audio, io

I am trying to stream audio using `rtp and audio stream`. The `rtp packets` are not received from the remote server. I am trying to debug, this warning is appearing in the `LogCat`. There seems to be no questions related to this error in SO. This is my code. I use it in service inside a thread.

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);

audioGroup.setMode(AudioGroup.MODE_ECHO_SUPPRESSION);
inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(getLocalIpAddress()); 
audioStream = new AudioStream(inetAddress);
audioStream.setCodec(AudioCodec.PCMU);
audioStream.setMode(RtpStream.MODE_NORMAL);

InetAddress inetAddressRemote = InetAddress.getByName(remoteIp);
audioStream.associate(inetAddressRemote, remotePort);              
audioStream.join(audioGroup);
```

Comment: Do you use simulator or real phone for testing? If real phone, can you try reproduce this behavior on other devices?

Comment: This was from the device. I connected device using `adb`.